# Access JIRA Rest API with token Jquery

Tags: jquery, oauth, jira-rest-api

I did follow post [JIRA Rest API error. Unrecognized token creating a issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816233/jira-rest-api-error-unrecognized-token-creating-a-issue) come with code as below, Token URL works when I using POSTMAN, but got error as below:
https://basde/rest/api/2/issue/JIR-8?callback=jQuery&_=9 401 ()

```
$.ajax({
type : "GET",
url:URL,
dataType : "jsonp",
async : false,
headers: {
  "X-Atlassian-Token": "Basic Token",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
},
error: function( req, status, err ) {
      console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err );
},
  success : (function(response) {
      // Alert Success Message
      alert("Melding succesvol ontvangen, bedankt!");
  })
});
```

Comment: A simple web search of that error will turn up thousands of results...and even full sites dedicated to it. You need to use a proxy

Comment: That problem got fixed, now I am hit 401